# returning reference of generic class

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I have this generic class :

```
template<class T>
class wwe{
public:
   T data;
   friend class Iterator;
   explicit wwe(T& data) : data(data){}
   //1- wwe<T>& getwwe();
   //2- wwe& getwwe();
}
```

Q1 : which one should I use .. 1-2 ? 

Q2 : what does data(data) do ?
Q3 : if I didn't define the whole 'Iterator' class inside the wwe class how should I define it .. if possible ?

 thanks

Comment: Q1: Use (2). It is equivalent to (1), but won't allow you to mistakenly type wrong template arguments. The other two questions are not clear enough for me to answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how I could mistakenly type wrong template arguments?

Comment: @Rawhi, `wwe<int>& getwwe();` In all seriousness, if you add another template parameter that's defaulted later, you have to go back and change it or you'll end up with the default all the time.

Comment: Why would you want to have an iterator class inside a class that contains only 1 element?

Comment: In regards to Q2 Am kinda new to c++ .. my question is what data(data) .. should do ?

Comment: `data(data)` is calling constructor for `T data` variable

Answer (score 1):

Q1 - doesn't matter.

Q2 - Like constructors normally work.  Nothing special.

Q3 - I see no evidence of an iterator or function that returns one or uses one.  Rather baffled by the question.